# Problem Flash8 lable

Tags: actionscript, label, flash-8

I have a problem: I am using Flash 8.
I have a label. I gave a name to label this as myLabel.
code in the actionscript I need access to perform this label
scrolling text:
I try but with _root.myLabel.scroll _root.myLabel always udefined.
Why?
I'm trying this code in a complex template that I downloaded.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try just "myLabel". This really matters when we figure out WHERE your actionscript is.

It sounds like you're possibly creating a scroller. [Here's a tutorial from Adobe on how to do it in Flash 8 and Actionscript 3.](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/192/tn_19237.html#main_8) Flash 8 / AS 2 permeates bad coding-practices by having you place actionscript on specific object-instances (textfields, movieclips, etc.) without really telling you what you're doing. It's like asking you to visually program in OOP without the foundation of WHY and HOW.

If you can, it'd be better for you to use [Actionscript 3, document-level classes, OOP, etc](http://www.lynda.com/search?q=actionscript&x=0&y=0).

Where is your actionscript? Is it in a frame at the top of your timeline? If you HAVE to use AS 2, or Flash 8, then put all your actionscript in a locked layer at the top of your timeline.

Comment: I also tried using MyLable but equal.
yes, I'm favendo a scroller. if I try my code into a new empty project that works well.
When I try to include it in the template no longer works. the problem is that I do not see this lable. the code runs fine .... but this is undefined. I insert this into a MovieClip

Comment: Is the movieclip on the stage? Do you have that I can review the code? What's the hierarchy of your template?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I'm not an expert in Actionscript and Flash programming, and then I can not explain how the model used.
I'm editing a flash template for a website ... in a movieclip that appears when you click on a main menu I need to make scrollable text here ..
I followed several tutorials to do this ... and it seems very easy. I tried this example in my project and this vacuum works well..
When I try this in your template is not working: the lable (for lable.scroll) is always undefined: how I could try to solve this problem?Sorry if I can not be very specific in my description.Thanks

Comment: Can you zip and post a link to the files? I think you've got a parent / child hierarchy issue here... Basically, your code is referencing a movieclip several layers deep and can't find the reference.